# Transforming a pandas df to a parquet-file-bytes-object

Tags: python, pandas, azure, pyarrow

I have a pandas dataframe and want to write it as a parquet file to the Azure file storage.

So far I have not been able to transform the dataframe directly into a bytes which I then can upload to Azure. 
My current workaround is to save it as a parquet file to the local drive, then read it as a bytes object which I can upload to Azure.

Can anyone tell me how I can transform a pandas dataframe directly to a "parquet file"-bytes object without writing it to a disk? The I/O operation is really slowing things down and it feels a lot like really ugly code...

```
# Transform the data_frame into a parquet file on the local drive    
data_frame.to_parquet('temp_p.parquet', engine='auto', compression='snappy')

# Read the parquet file as bytes.
with open("temp_p.parquet", mode='rb') as f:
     fileContent = f.read()

     # Upload the bytes object to Azure
     service.create_file_from_bytes(share_name, file_path, file_name, fileContent, index=0, count=len(fileContent))
```

I'm looking to implement something like this, where the transform_functionality returns a bytes object:

```
my_bytes = data_frame.transform_functionality()
service.create_file_from_bytes(share_name, file_path, file_name, my_bytes, index=0, count=len(my_bytes))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a solution, I will post it here in case anyone needs to do the same task. After writing it with the `to_parquet` file to a **buffer**, I get the bytes object out of the buffer with the `.getvalue()` functionality as follows:

```
buffer = BytesIO()
data_frame.to_parquet(buffer, engine='auto', compression='snappy')

service.create_file_from_bytes(share_name, file_path, file_name, buffer.getvalue(), index=0, count=buffer.getbuffer().nbytes )
```

Comment: FWIW, in testing with python 3.6.1, pandas 0.24.0, pyarrow 0.9.0, and fastparquet 0.2.1, this solution only works with the pyarrow engine. Using fastparquet gives `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cribber ! Had a similar problem in another cloud service, the `.getvalue()` made it (after 2 hs of stackoverflowing..)